# How to get C (not C++) syntax highlighting in Visual Studio (2010)?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was doing some small exercises in C with a friend, and I kept using keywords from newer languages (e.g. bool, new) out of habit.  It took me a while to realize that was the issue because VS kept highlighting them as keywords, even though they aren't in C.

I made sure all of my files were *.c, and I set the project properties to compile as C.  However, the editor always added syntax highlightint for C++ keywords in addition to C keywords.  Is there any way to tell Visual Studio that I just want plain C?

Using VS2010 if it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot.  [This is a known bug in Visual Studio.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/516920/predefine-macro-problems)  The "Intellisense" mechanism which is used for syntax coloring in Visual Studio is based on the EDG C++ compiler which Microsoft bought, since their Visual C/C++ compiler is poorly suited for the incremental parsing required to handle on-the-fly analysis of incomplete code.  And the EDG compiler is C++ only.

You can see an example of this by creating a foo.c file which compiles as C.  Then add to the file the following lines:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 #error C++ is what I am
 #else
 #error A bunch of C code!
 #endif
```

When you compile your program you will see the error message "A bunch of C code!"  But when you look at the Visual Studio editor window, the C side will be grayed out and marked inactive, and only the C++ side will be colored!  That's because the Intellisense syntax colorer, based on the EDG C++ compiler, believes that everything is C++.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that some C++ features have been adopted by C (C99 std), such as the C++-style comments (//), or the boolean (bool) data type.