# Is it wise to use the `this` keyword in C?

Tags: c, class, this, c99

Basically, I have a inline function in C:

```
struct array {
    unsigned long size;
    void* items;
};
typedef struct array* Array;
inline Array array_create(unsigned long initsize);
inline void  array_free(Array this);
```

Am I free to use the `this` keyword in this kind of situation, or is it better to avoid it, and why (not)?

EDIT: This question originated from a bug in my code where I used `inline void array_free(Array array);` which changed the result of `sizeof(array);` and gave me the idea to use `this` instead of adapting to the (in my opinion ugly) `sizeof(struct array);`.

Comment: Why did you tag this C++? Anyway, `this` isn't a keyword in C, so it isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: Why specifically `this`, and not `new` and `delete`, for example?

Comment: 'this' is a C++ only keyword representing a const pointer to a class instance and is directly accessible from within class member functions.

Comment: `this` is not a keyword in C.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think that's why OP is asking if it's "wise", not if it's "valid"

Comment: @juanchopanza because I know `this` is not a keyword in C (which is the answer that I'll get if I tag it for C) but I would like to know if C++ programmers mind to see this syntax (even though it is C), or if they would prefer something like `array`. My goal is to keep the code readable.

Comment: @Nasser: That doesn't change the fact that the question is based on a false premise. "Is it wise to use the smallest positive number as an initial value" would be similarly flawed.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, as long as you don't intend to port this code to C++ "as is". In fact, if your intention is simply to denote that `array_free` is a "method" of `Array`, then it actually improves readability by communicating your intent to the reader.

Comment: If you're not sure if something is ambiguous or confusing then it stands to reason that other people also might find it ambiguous or confusing....that's what being ambiguous and confusing means, so you can be pretty sure that it is.  Writing code that is ambiguous and confusing is bad, so just don't do it.

Comment: In C++, you can use the this keyword. Note however, that you cannot use it  in initializer lists. It is therefore wise to name your members differently than arguments in addition to using the this keyword.

Comment: *"In C++, you can use the this keyword."* - No, you cannot. `void f(int this) {}` is a compiler error.

Comment: Sure, you're free to use any non-reserved word in any way you want to.  This really is an opinion question, though.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer it is more about readability, but yes, technically readability is all about opinion.

Comment: I propose `self` as an alternative.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY Exactly.  I think it's a terribly crazy idea, but hey, that's just my opinion.  It's completely legal.

Comment: @el.pescado That is a great idea actually. Might stick with that.

Comment: Is that why the title is "Is it wise to use the `this` keyword in C?" Because `this` is NOT a keyword in C?

Comment: @juanchopanza But it IS a keyword in C++, which is both why I tagged the question C++ and why added the `keyword` part. My purpose is to make clear that `this` (or `self`, great idea) refers to a class-like object, which might be modified inside the function. Using something like `thing` would not be very imformative for people who only read the defentition (`void array_set(Array thing, unsigned long loc, void* it);` is not at all readable to me) I initialy used `array` for this, but as you might have read in the question, this conflicts with the defined structs.

Comment: Then you should ask if it is OK to use the C++ keyword in C. But what about all the other C++ keywords?

Comment: @juanchopanza For other C++ keywords it would most likely not be possible to use them with the same purpose in C. The `this` keyword can have have the same meaning in C and C++, (or at least in my code) which is why I asked if it would be wise to use it in C. (It has the same meaning, but it is not the same programming language, which is why I asked if it would be confusing and unreadable if it is seen in C code)

Comment: As a C++ programmer I would be **extremely** confused that `void  array_free(Array this);` is passing a pointer and not an object by value. IMO that is a lot worse than using `this`.  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `this` in any fashion you want is totally valid C.

What you have to ask yourself, by the way these apply to any C++ reserved words like `class`, `final` etc, is :

- Do I use a program that highlights `this` as a keyword conveing the wrong message ? e.g. Visual Studio highlights `this` even when you're in a `.c` file so some confusion may arise.
- Do I plan to promote my code to C++ in the future ? In such a case you'll have some extra work to do that could be avoided.
- Does my code interact with C++ ? This is not a problem per se but you have to bear in mind that your code will interact with C++ programmers as well. And you don't won't to confuse people that may not be aware of C in great detail (even though someone may say it's their duty do be aware of what they're doing when reading another language).

Since `this` is something that can be avoided I find using it immoral but not incorrect.

I'm not saying you have to study C++ prior to writing C, but once you know something, it's a good practice to make good use of it.

A subtle problem you may cause is to make your code 'uncallable' from C++ for example a

```
#define this some_definition
```

in a C header file that is later included from C++ may have weird effects to your code.

Comment: `final` is an identifier in recent versions of C++, not a keyword.

Comment: Your first point is not entirely correct. The VS IDE will respect the `/TC` compiler flag, not the filename ending, and use the correct color for `this`.

Comment: @Peter wanted to talk about reserved words in general. Chaged keyword to the term _reserved word_

Comment: @ChristianHackl VS's was the easiest example I could find. I have ended up with a `.c` file highlighting `this` many times. What you say does not apply to all versions. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5645868/2567683)

Comment: @ChristianHackl Also I don't know if this is fixed since VS12, I'd like some info if you have any but I think EDG remains C++ only

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: I don't know, I just tested it with VC 2013 Express Edition and it worked fine there. But only if you set that compilation unit to the correct "compile as C" flag (in fact, it then works even with *.cpp files).

Answer (score 11):

It's technically correct because C is not C++, so `this` is not a keyword in C.

Whether it's *wise*, now that's a different question. If there is any chance that this piece of code will ever be compiled as C++, then an identifier called `this` will break the code.

Answer (score 5):

The reasons not to use `this` in standard C is that it makes your code:

1. Slightly less readable, due to the "well-known" usage of `this` in C++. Your code can look as if it's C++ and an uninformed reader can easily get confused.
2. Unportable to C++. If you (or someone else) ever want to take this code and use it in a C++ compilation, it will fail. That's a downside and an upside at the same time, since getting an error can be indicative that care must be taken, where's not getting one might let important issues slip.

Comment: I did not yet think about people making asumptions about what language my code is. I will probably accept this answer if noone comes with better reasons to (not) use `this` in C.

Answer (score 1):

As it is already mentioned, you can use any non-reserved keyword as a variable name.
However, I suggest to use something like 'pThis', or '[struct name]This' or similar to express your intent of using a C struct together with functions that are taking as first argument a pointer to [struct name] instance, and are meant to be used in a similar manner as member functions of a C++ class.

This way your code may be more readable and your intent more understandable by someone who is using it.

Comment: `pThis` is not really my style, which unfortunately makes my code less readable. @el.pescado had the great idea to use `self` though, which I might stick with.

Comment: Of course, I just threw in a couple of name ideas, but the final style is certainly one that should increase readability.

Comment: Yeah, I will probably use a alternative for `this`, most likely `self`, like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what your objective is.

If your C code program will always be built with a C compiler that is not a C++ compiler, then it makes no difference whether you use `this` as an identifier in your code.   It is not a reserved identifier, so you are free to use it.

The potential problem with that premise is that a number of mainstream C compilers are actually C++ compilers, or they support some C++ features as extensions, so they may reject your code (or - less likely - do something with it that you don't expect).   It is not possible to predict with absolute certainty that the vendor of your compiler(s) of choice will never (even if they give you a promise in writing) release a future version of their C compiler that will reject or do something unexpected with your code.   The likelihood of this happening is relatively low, but non-zero.

In the end you need to decide what risk you are willing to take with maintaining your code in future.

Of course, if you are a C fanatic who wants your code to have an incompatibility with C++  (yes, such people do exist) then using a number of keywords or reserved identifiers that are specific to C++, as well as using such keywords or identifiers that are specific to (more recent versions of) C may be a worthwhile approach.

Comment: I did not know that there were C(99) compilers implementing C++ features. I do not intent to break C++, I just want to make sure that my code is as fast as possible. This gives another great reason not to use `this` though: It might break some C compilers implementing C++ features.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY: What does this have to do with execution speed? Or do you mean compilation speed?

Comment: @peter Do you have examples of C compilers that would barf when encountering `this`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl It is about using C++ vs C. I am afraid that using C++ instead of C might make my code slow enough to keep its current C competitor faster. Also note that the `array` type is not at all the main focus of my project, but since I am using many class-like code in C and will probably encounter more places where `this` can be used I did ask this question.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY: C is not faster than C++ when you use modern tools. But you can use both languages incorrectly to make your program slower than it needs to be.

Comment: @yuan - C compilers will not barf at encountering `this` (except in code with some other  error).  C++ compilers, however, do reject usage of `this` outside the context of non-static member functions.

Answer (score 0):

In C you do not have the `this` keyword. Only in C++ and in a class, so your code is C and you use your `this` variable as a local method parameter, where you access the array struct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If the code happens to get compiled as C++, it is not your fault. However, in case that happens, other things won't be accepted; the fact that you likely assign to `items` without a cast, for instance, because C++ does not allow that unlike C.